# Unable to pan the camera East enough in Euro Truck Simulator 2

Tags: mods, euro-truck-simulator-2

Now that I have the DLC for ETS2, I would like to explore the new areas added, however, I cannot seem to pan the map far enough to the East as it will just snap back to Wroclaw as soon as it gets past it. (See the image)

[image: Wroclaw map]

If I zoom completely in, I'm able to go just a tad further than the image above shows. I'm using mods, which cannot be uninstalled on a save, but I have tested that the map works fine without mods, on another save. I'm so far in the game that I would hate to start over again and I like the mods I have now.

**Is there a way for me to make the camera work?** I'm open to any suggestions from settings files to new mods.

My current mods are

- Elegance - Destinos
- Elegance 360 (seems to be the cause, but it's also my current vehicle)
- OversizeLoadMod (v1.4.1)
- Realistic Physics Mod v7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any mod that has a `game_data.sii` file can cause the problem. You only need a small tweak to fix this, that is if you can't find newer versions of your mods. You'll need [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

Mods are loaded in alphabetic order (a-z) so you only need to edit the last mod (to be loaded) that contains the `game_data.sii` file. So start by opening `Realistic Physics Mod`. Right-click on it, under the 7-zip sub-menu in the context menu, select `open archive`. You'll find a folder called `def`, inside that check for `game_data.sii` (if you don't find it, skip to the next mod). Right click on it and select edit. Find the following lines

```
camera_limits_max[4]: (33000.0, 42000.0)
camera_limits_max[5]: (23000.0, 32000.0)
camera_limits_max[6]: (21000.0, 33000.0)
camera_limits_max[7]: (15000.0, 26000.0)
```

and replace with

```
camera_limits_max[4]: (45000.0, 42000.0)
camera_limits_max[5]: (43000.0, 32000.0)
camera_limits_max[6]: (34000.0, 33000.0)
camera_limits_max[7]: (15000.0, 26000.0)
```

save and exit.